# Loading .txt data into 10x256 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mapping

I'm trying to load some text files into numpy arrays. The .txt files represent pixels of an image where each pixel is given an arbitrary relative coordinate between -10 and +10 (for x) and 0 and 10 for y. In total, the image is 10x256 pixels. The catch is that each pixel isn't given an RGB values it is given a list of intensities that corresponds to the wavelength vales in the first /n separated "header". Each coordinate is given as the two first tab separated item and the first entry only has "0 0" because that  The format of the text files is as follows:

```
Line 1: "0 0  625.15360  625.69449  626.23538 ..." (two coordinates followed by the wavelengths)
Line 2: "-10.00000  -10.00000   839   841   833   843   838   847 ..."
Line 3: "-10.00000   -9.92157   838   839   838 ..."
```

Where 839 and 838 represent the intensity of the wavelength 625.15360 for two different adjacent pixels one on top of another (with a small change in y). Furthermore, 841 and 839 would be the intensity of the 625.69449 wavelength, and so on and so forth.

My reasoning thus far has been to iterate through the file using `np.genfromtxt()` and adding to a new array 3D numpy array with variables (x,y, lambda) each being assigned one single intensity value. Also, I think it would make much more sense if x and y spanned from 0-9 and 0-255 respectively to represent the image instead of the arbitrary relative coordinates given in the data...

Problem: I don't know how to load the data into a 3x3 (stuck figuring out 2x2) and I can't seem to slice properly...

What I have so far:

```
intensity_array2 = np.zeros([len(unique_y),len(unique_x)], dtype= int)

for element in np.nditer(intensity_array2, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    for i in range(len(unique_y)):
        for j in range(len(unique_x)):
            with open(os.path.join(path_name,right_file)) as rf:
                intensity_array2[i,j] = np.genfromtxt(rf, skip_header = (i*j)+j, delimiter = " ")
```

Where `len(unique_y) = 10` and `len(unique_x) = 256` are found in a function above.

Comment: If anyone has any idea about how to to simply load values iteratively into a 3x3 array that would be a good start :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Lukeclh's answer, try:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(rf)
```

Then, cleave off the wavelength values

```
wavelengths = data[0]
intensities = data[1:]
```

We can now rearrange the data using reshape:

```
intensitiesshaped = np.reshape(intensities, (len(unique_x),len(unique_y),-1))
```

The "-1" value says 'the rest goes here'.

We still have the leading values (of on each of these arrays.  To trim them, we can do:

```
wavelengths = wavelengths[2:]
intensitiesshaped = intensities[:,:,2:]
```

This just throws the information in the first two indices away.  If you need to retain it you'll have to do something a bit more sophisticated.

Comment: actually, i still get an error like this one:     Line #2561 (got 3025 columns instead of 1725)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your file format, so forgive me if this does not make sense. However, if there is any way you can load all the data in at once I am sure it will run much faster.  It appears to me that you can use this to get all the data into memory:

data = np.genfromtxt(rf, delimiter = " ")

Then create your 3D array:

intensity_array2 = np.zeros( (10, 256, num_wavlengths) )

Then fill in the values of the 3D array:

intensity_array2[ data[:,0], data[:,1], :] = data[:, 2:]

This will not work exactly because your x and y indices can go negative--you might need to add an offset in this case.  Also, if your input file is in a predictable format, you may be able to simply call np.reshape() on the data matrix to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
 I tried what you said but I got the following error or something like it for every line 1 to 2561:

`code` Line #1694 (got 2944 columns instead of 1725)

This leads me to believe that the columns may not all be the same size...

Comment: About the negative indices I don't really mind that they go negative if I could re-label them from 0-9 and 0-255 I would be perfectly okay with that.